# How to use protobuf from remote Artifactory?

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

There is a protobuf that my project needs. The protobuf itself is in another repo altogether owned by a completely different team. However they do publish their artifacts on my company's internal Artifactory.

How can I use that (non Bazel) protobuf in my Bazel project?

This is the direction I was trying to go before I hit a deadend.

WORKSPACE file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive", "http_file")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto",
    sha256 = "80d3a4ec17354cccc898bfe32118edd934f851b03029d63ef3fc7c8663a7415c",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-5.3.0-21.5",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/5.3.0-21.5.tar.gz",
    ],
)
load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()

http_file(
    name = "some-service-protobuf",
    url = "https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/x/y/some-service-protobuf.dbgrel.zip",
)
```

BUILD file:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
proto_library(
    name = "SomeService.proto",
)
```

The resources I'm trying to use:

1. https://bazel.build/reference/be/java#java_proto_library
2. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto

Is fetching proto files from remote URL possible? How show I do it after copying those files in my repo.

Comment: The advice [on your latest post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588845/getting-a-using-type-x-from-an-indirect-dependency-in-java-test-suite-even-whe) applies here too. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom. Use a spell-checker, and use the Markdown editor to apply formatting for readability. Bear in mind that questions are kept for posterity, and are intended to be useful for future engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using `http_archive` instead:

https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive

And then use the `build_file` or `build_file_content` attributes to add the build file with the `proto_library` definition to the external workspace created from the zip file:

```
http_archive(
    name = "some-service-protobuf",
    url = "https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/x/y/some-service-protobuf.dbgrel.zip",
    build_file = "BUILD.some_service",
)
```

`BUILD.some_service`:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
proto_library(
    name = "some_service_proto",
    srcs = ["SomeService.proto"],
)
```

Then in another build file you can do something like:

```
java_proto_library(
  name = "some_service_java_protobuf",
  deps = ["@some-service-protobuf//:some_service_proto"],
)
```

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot! one follow up question: if i wanted to add a dependency to this proto_library, how do i do it? i tried with "deps = ["//src/main/proto:timestamp_java_proto"]" but it didnt work