# Getting a "Using type x from an indirect dependency" in java_test_suite even when x is declared under dependency

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

My CustomTest.java has this import:

> com.google.protobuf.Timestamp

I'm using java_test_suite to run tests in my BUILD file like so:

```
java_test_suite(
    name = "all-tests",
    srcs = glob(["src/test/java/**/*.java"]),
    runner = "junit5",
    test_suffixes = ["Test.java"],
    runtime_deps = JUNIT5_DEPS,
    deps = [
        ":mylib",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto",
        artifact("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api"),
        artifact("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params"),
    ] + deps,
)
```

However when I run tests on it using:

`bazel test //:all-tests`

I'm getting this error:

```
src/test/java/com/x/CustomTest.java:75: error: [strict] Using type com.google.protobuf.Timestamp from an indirect dependency (TOOL_INFO: "@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto wrapped in java_proto_library"). See command below **
private static Timestamp timestampFromMilli(long milli) {
               ^
 ** Please add the following dependencies: 
  @com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto to //:src/test/java/com/x/CustomTest 
 ** You can use the following buildozer command: 
buildozer 'add deps @com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto' //:src/test/java/com/x/CustomTest
```

What do I need to do exactly? I tried using the buildozer command but all I got was:

> rule 'src/test/java/com/x/CustomTest' not found

Where do I need to add this `@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto`?

Comment: Please try to avoid txtspk here (pls, thx, etc). It's annoying, but it's also less readable. Stick to English technical writing if you can.

Comment: Useful boilerplate advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: The personal pronoun in English is a capital "I". Please always capitalise it.

Comment: @halfer One comment on formatting would have sufficed. Instead you left 4.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If there are multiple sub-themes to the feedback I tend to write a comment for each. I offer feedback frequently to contributors, so squashing items into less comments isn't something I'd object to, and I'd rather give advice in a way that contributors find palatable. Perhaps I could have done two here rather than three... there is a length limitation on comments too, rightly or wrongly. Of course the fourth is on a different message - and there is no getting around needing an additional comment for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at protobuf's build files, it looks like `timestamp_proto` is a plain `proto_library`:

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/BUILD.bazel#L70-L74

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/BUILD.bazel#L64-L68

and so per the advice here:

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/BUILD.bazel#L19-L25

you might just need to use `java_proto_library` to make the java version of the proto:

```
java_proto_library(
  name = "timestamp_java_proto",
  deps = ["@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto"],
)
```

and then use that in the deps of your `java_test_suite` instead of the `timestamp_proto`.

Just a guess, but the error message is not very helpful maybe because there happens to be a Timestamp java class in the deps of the plain proto library, and Strict deps is finding that one in the test's indirect dependencies. Might be worth filing a bug about it on https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues